# NDSolve unable to handle discontinuities

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, discontinuity

I'm trying to solve a set of ordinary non-linear differential equations but running into issues. Specifically, after supplying Mathematica the below definitions and evaluating the `NDSolve` command in the last code sample, I get the error

> NDSolve cannot handle discontinuities where the argument of
>   `DiracDelta` depends on any variable besides the temporal independent
>   variable.

`DiracDelta`s appear once Mathematica performs the symbolic derivatives that act on `HeavisideTheta` in `DiscTfJ`.

I believe the error message is due to `DiracDelta` being evaluated before all variables were replaced by their numerical values during `NDSolve`'s operation. I tried to prevent this by placing `?NumericQ` at various places behind function arguments but without any luck. Any suggestions how to get `NDSolve` to solve this system of ODEs would be much appreciated!

### Update

Implementing the excellent suggestions by J.M. and xzczd `NDSolve` now runs until about $t = -3$ at which point it throws the error

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/Sqrt[0.] encountered.
>
> NDSolve::nlnum: The function value
>   {Indeterminate,0.000687141,0.00245154 +0. I,-4.25825+0. I} is not a
>   list of numbers with dimensions {4} at
>   {t,g2[t],Zk[t],[Lambda]k[t],[Rho]0[t],NDSolve`s\$4620[t],NDSolve`s\$4613[t],NDSolve`s\$4619[t],NDSolve`s\$4621[t]}
>   = {-3.0213,0.,0.999229,0.467672,2.13825,-1,1,-1,-1}.

Haven't identified the cause of this yet.

---

### Auxiliary functions

**Custom square root** with branch cut along negative real $x$-axis.  Second argument $y$ decides which branch to take: upper branch if $\text{Re}(y) \geq 0$,  lower branch if $\text{Re}(y)<0$.

```
sqrt[x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ]=Piecewise[{{I Sqrt[-x],Re[x]<0&&Re[y]>=0},{-I Sqrt[-x],Re[x]<0&&Re[y]<0}},Sqrt[x]]

Unprotect[Power];sqrt[x_,y_]^2:=x;Protect[Power];

Derivative[1,0][sqrt][x_,y_]=1/(2sqrt[x,y]);

Derivative[0,1][sqrt][x_,y_]=0;
```

**Partial fraction decomposition**

Denominator coefficients $\alpha_k^{\pm\pm}$

```
\[Alpha]k[1,1][m2t_,g2t_,z_,c_]:=1/2 (1/c+m2t/z-I g2t/z)+I sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z+I g2t/z)^2,-(1/c-m2t/z)];
\[Alpha]k[1,2][m2t_,g2t_,z_,c_]:=1/2 (1/c+m2t/z+I g2t/z)-I sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z-I g2t/z)^2,(1/c-m2t/z)];
\[Alpha]k[2,1][m2t_,g2t_,z_,c_]:=1/2 (1/c+m2t/z-I g2t/z)-I sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z+I g2t/z)^2,-(1/c-m2t/z)];
\[Alpha]k[2,2][m2t_,g2t_,z_,c_]:=1/2 (1/c+m2t/z+I g2t/z)+I sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z-I g2t/z)^2,(1/c-m2t/z)];
\[Alpha]k[1,0][m2t_,g2t_,z_,c_]:=1/2 (1/c+m2t/z)+1/2 (I sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z+I g2t/z)^2,-(1/c-m2t/z)]-I sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z-I g2t/z)^2,(1/c-m2t/z)]);
\[Alpha]k[2,0][m2t_,g2t_,z_,c_]:=1/2 (1/c+m2t/z)-1/2 (I sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z+I g2t/z)^2,-(1/c-m2t/z)]-I sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z-I g2t/z)^2,(1/c-m2t/z)]);
```

Numerator coefficients $\beta_k^{\pm\pm}$

```
\[Beta]k[1,1][m2t_,g2t_,z_,c_]:=1/(2z)+I 1/(4z) (1/c-m2t/z+I g2t/z) 1 /sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z+I g2t/z)^2,-(1/c-m2t/z)];
\[Beta]k[1,2][m2t_,g2t_,z_,c_]:=1/(2z)-I 1/(4z) (1/c-m2t/z-I g2t/z) 1 /sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z-I g2t/z)^2,(1/c-m2t/z)];
\[Beta]k[2,1][m2t_,g2t_,z_,c_]:=1/(2z)-I 1/(4z) (1/c-m2t/z+I g2t/z) 1 /sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z+I g2t/z)^2,-(1/c-m2t/z)];
\[Beta]k[2,2][m2t_,g2t_,z_,c_]:=1/(2z)+I 1/(4z) (1/c-m2t/z-I g2t/z) 1 /sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z-I g2t/z)^2,(1/c-m2t/z)];
\[Beta]k[1,0][m2t_,g2t_,z_,c_]:=1/(2z)+I 1/(8z) (1/c-m2t/z+I g2t/z) 1 /sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z+I g2t/z)^2,-(1/c-m2t/z)]-I 1/(8z) (1/c-m2t/z-I g2t/z) 1 /sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z-I g2t/z)^2,(1/c-m2t/z)];
\[Beta]k[2,0][m2t_,g2t_,z_,c_]:=1/(2z)-I 1/(8z) (1/c-m2t/z+I g2t/z) 1 /sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z+I g2t/z)^2,-(1/c-m2t/z)]+I 1/(8z) (1/c-m2t/z-I g2t/z) 1 /sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2t/z-I g2t/z)^2,(1/c-m2t/z)];
```

### Threshold functions

$I_j$

```
ker[4]=1/(2\[Pi]^2) 1/32 Sum[\[Alpha]k[i,j][m2,g2,z,c]^2 Log[\[Alpha]k[i,j][m2,g2,z,c]],{i,2},{j,2}];

tfI[0][m2_,g2_,z_,0,c_,4]=(m2^2-g2^2)/(8z^2)+Function[4#-2m2 D[#,m2]-2g2 D[#,g2]][ker[4]];

tfI[1][m2_,g2_,z_,0,c_,4]=1/(2\[Pi]^2) 1/4 m2/z^2+Function[2D[#,m2]-2m2 D[#,{m2,2}]-2g2 D[#,m2,g2]][ker[4]];

tfI[2][m2_,g2_,z_,0,c_,4]=-(1/(2\[Pi]^2)) 1/4 1/z^2+Function[2m2 D[#,{m2,3}]+2g2 D[#,{m2,2},g2]][ker[4]];
```

$\text{Disc}_{q_0} \, J$

```
discTfJ[q0_,m1_,m2_,g1_,g2_,z1_,z2_,0,c_,4]=Function[q0 D[#,q0]+2m1 D[#,m1]+2m2 D[#,m2]+2g1 D[#,g1]+2g2 D[#,g2]][
Module[{a1,a2,b1,b2},Sum[(a1=\[Alpha]k[i,0][m1,g1,z1,c];a2=\[Alpha]k[j,0][m2,g2,z2,c];b1=\[Beta]k[i,0][m1,g1,z1,c];b2=\[Beta]k[j,0][m2,g2,z2,c];
(b1 b2)/(8 \[Pi] q0) ((q0^4-2q0^2 (a1+a2)+(a1-a2)^2)/(4q0^2))^(1/2) UnitStep[Re[q0-Re[Sqrt[a1]+Sqrt[a2]]]]),{i,2},{j,2}]]];
```

$\partial_{q^2} \, J$

```
dqTfJ[q0_,m1_,m2_,g1_,g2_,z1_,z2_,0,c_,4]=1/(2\[Pi]^2) 1/2 Re[Function[-2#-q0 D[#,q0]-2m1 D[#,m1]-2m2 D[#,m2]-2g1 D[#,g1]-2g2 D[#,g2]][
Module[{a1,a2,b1,b2},1/4 Sum[a1=\[Alpha]k[i,sig1][m1,g1,z1,c];a2=\[Alpha]k[j,sig2][m2,g2,z2,c];b1=\[Beta]k[i,sig1][m1,g1,z1,c];b2=\[Beta]k[j,sig2][m2,g2,z2,c];
b1 b2 Piecewise[{{(((a1-a2)^2-(a1+a2) q0^2)/(4 q0^4 Sqrt[-(a1-a2)^2+2 (a1+a2) q0^2-q0^4]) (ArcTan[(q0^2+a1-a2)/Sqrt[-q0^4-(a1-a2)^2+2 q0^2 (a1+a2)]]+ArcTan[(q0^2-a1+a2)/Sqrt[-q0^4-(a1-a2)^2+2 q0^2 (a1+a2)]])+1/(4 q0^2)-((a1-a2) (Log[a1]-Log[a2]))/(8 q0^4)),a1-a2!=0},{1/(4q0^2)-a1/(q0^2 Sqrt[4a1 q0^2-q0^4]) ArcTan[ q0^2/Sqrt[4a1 q0^2-q0^4]],a1-a2==0}}],{i,2},{j,2},{sig1,2},{sig2,2}]]]];

dqTfJ[0, m1_, m2_, g1_, g2_, z1_, z2_, 0, c_, 4] = 
  1/(2 \[Pi]^2) 1/
   2 Re[Function[-2 # - 2 m1 D[#, m1] - 2 m2 D[#, m2] - 
       2 g1 D[#, g1] - 2 g2 D[#, g2]][
     Module[{a1, a2, b1, b2}, 
      1/4 Sum[a1 = \[Alpha]k[i, sig1][m1, g1, z1, c]; 
        a2 = \[Alpha]k[j, sig2][m2, g2, z2, c]; 
        b1 = \[Beta]k[i, sig1][m1, g1, z1, c]; 
        b2 = \[Beta]k[j, sig2][m2, g2, z2, c];
        b1 b2 Piecewise[{{((-a1^2 + a2^2 + 
              2 a1 a2 (Log[a1] - Log[a2]))/(8 (a1 - a2)^3)), 
            a1 - a2 != 0}, {-(1/(24 a1)), a1 - a2 == 0}}], {i, 2}, {j,
          2}, {sig1, 2}, {sig2, 2}]]]];
```

### Flow Equations

```
\[Rho]0Flow[\[Rho]0_,\[Lambda]k_,\[Eta]k_,g2_,Z1_,c_,d_,N_]:=-(2+\[Eta]k)\[Rho]0-(3/2 tfI[1][2\[Rho]0 \[Lambda]k,g2,Z1,0,c,d]+(N-1)/2 tfI[1][0,0,1,0,c,d])

\[Lambda]kFlow[\[Rho]0_,\[Lambda]k_,\[Eta]k_,g2_,Z1_,c_,d_,N_]:=2\[Eta]k \[Lambda]k-\[Lambda]k^2 (9/2 tfI[2][2\[Rho]0 \[Lambda]k,g2,Z1,0,c,d]+(N-1)/2 tfI[2][0,0,1,0,c,d])

g2Flow[q0_,\[Rho]0_,\[Lambda]k_,\[Eta]k_,g2_,Z1_,c_,d_,N_]:=(\[Eta]k-2)g2-2\[Rho]0 \[Lambda]k^2 (9 discTfJ[q0,2\[Rho]0 \[Lambda]k,2\[Rho]0 \[Lambda]k,g2,g2,Z1,Z1,0,c,d]-(N-1)discTfJ[q0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,c,d])

ZkFlow[Zk_,\[Rho]0_,\[Lambda]k_,g2_,Z1_,c_,d_]:=2Zk \[Rho]0 \[Lambda]k^2 dqTfJ[0,2\[Rho]0 \[Lambda]k,0,g2,0,Z1,1,0,c,d]
```

### Solving the flow equations

```
Module[{runner = 0, counter = 0},
  With[{\[Eta]k = -Zk'[t]/Zk[t], Z1 = 1, c = 1, d = 4, N = 2},
   \[Rho]0\[Lambda]k\[Eta]kg2Run[1] = 
    NDSolve[{\[Rho]0'[
        t] == \[Rho]0Flow[\[Rho]0[t], \[Lambda]k[t], \[Eta]k, g2[t], 
        Z1, c, d, N],
      \[Lambda]k'[
        t] == \[Lambda]kFlow[\[Rho]0[t], \[Lambda]k[t], \[Eta]k, 
        g2[t], Z1, c, d, N],
      Zk'[t] == 
       ZkFlow[Zk[t], \[Rho]0[t], \[Lambda]k[t], g2[t], Z1, c, d],
      g2'[t] == 
       g2Flow[Sqrt[
        2 \[Rho]0[t] \[Lambda]k[t]/Z1], \[Rho]0[t], \[Lambda]k[
         t], \[Eta]k, g2[t], Z1, c, d, N],
      \[Rho]0[0] == 0.02, \[Lambda]k[0] == 0.5, Zk[0] == 1, 
      g2[0] == 0}, {\[Rho]0, \[Lambda]k, Zk, g2}, {t, -10, 0},
     StepMonitor :> 
      counter++ If[Abs[t] > runner, 
        Print@Chop[{counter, Round[t, 1], 
           E^(2 t) \[Rho]0[t], \[Lambda]k[t], Zk[t], E^(2 t) g2[t]}]; 
        runner++]]];
  Plot[E^(2 t) \[Rho]0[t] /. \[Rho]0\[Lambda]k\[Eta]kg2Run[
      1], {t, -10, 0}, PlotRange -> {0, All}]
   Plot[\[Lambda]k[t] /. \[Rho]0\[Lambda]k\[Eta]kg2Run[1], {t, -10, 0}]
   Plot[-Zk'[t]/Zk[t] /. \[Rho]0\[Lambda]k\[Eta]kg2Run[1], {t, -10, 0}]
   Plot[E^(2 t) g2[t] /. \[Rho]0\[Lambda]k\[Eta]kg2Run[1], {t, -10, 
     0}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Prolly should be repeated again: keep `HeavisideTheta[]` to symbolics, and use `UnitStep[]` for numerics.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the tip! I'll be keeping that in mind from now on.

Comment: @xzczd 1. Damn, can't believe I missed. Thanks for spotting that! 2. Are you sure? Because this construction has worked for me just as expected on many occasions. 3. Same here, it usually works, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @xzczd I just realized that I copied the wrong `NDSolve` command into this question. This one works because it sets to zero the problematic variable `g2[t]`. I will edit the question to include the command that's actually causing me trouble. Could you try again with that?

Comment: @xzczd 1. I removed `q0` from my code and simply replaced it with its definition `Sqrt[2 \[Rho]0 \[Lambda]k/Z1]`. 2. That is because of `q0[\[Rho]0,\[Lambda]k,Z1]` in `g2Flow` which I had forgotten to remove.

Comment: @xzczd I usually use `With` and just switched to a replacement rule to see if it affected the error messages in any way. I included my `NDSolve` command that uses `With`. Not sure what you mean with "If you just want to type e.g. `\[Rho]0` instead of `\[Rho]0[t]`, ..."

Comment: I mean, personally I think definition like `DiscTfJ[q0_,m1_,m2_,g1_,g2_,z1_,z2_,0,c_,4]` only makes the code dirty. Back to your problem, those `ArcTan` terms are suspicious, do you need `ArcTan[y/x]` or `ArcTan[x, y]`?

Comment: @xzczd I tested both and they actually give the same result which is even the one I expected (except for a sign mistake somewhere). `ArcTan[y/x]` seems to run about 10 % percent faster than `ArcTan[x, y]`. However, they also both still throw the error "Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/Sqrt[0.] encountered." near $t = -3$ where `g2[t]` suddenly becomes non-zero. At this point all variables attain a small imaginary part which is unexpected/undesired. The real part seems unaffected but it does slow down the calculation quite a bit.

Comment: @xzczd I believe the singularity is caused by the term `DiscTfJ[q0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,c,d]` in `g2Flow`. Running `Plot[Re@discTfJ[Sqrt[2 \[Rho]0[t] \[Lambda]k[t]], 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,1, 4] /. \[Rho]0\[Lambda]k\[Eta]kg2Run[1], {t, -10, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> All]` shows a sharp albeit finite peak but that is probably due to the finite plot resolution. Increasing `PlotPoints` also  increases the value of the peak. Do you of any tools/methods how I could diagnose this further?

Comment: Adding `Method -> StiffnessSwitching` to `NDSolve` results in a solution (I'm not sure if this solution is reliable, `StiffnessSwitching` sometimes leads to wrong solution), takes about 500 seconds on my laptop. (In _v9.0.1_ I also need to add `Re@` to the RHS of the equation system and add `?NumericQ` to those `*Flow` function, or `NDSolve` won't even start calculating, but this seems to be unnecessary for your version? )

Comment: `Method -> {FixedStep, Method -> Automatic}` leads to (almost) the same solution in about 343 seconds. Something similar to `NDSolveValue[{0 ==(*D[u[t],t]*)D[Sqrt[u[t]^2], t] + 1, u[0] == -1}, u, {t, 0, 4}]` might have happened in your code, but it's hard to go deeper given its… complexity.

Comment: @xzcz Thanks so much for your continued help! You're right I don't need to add `Re@`nor `?NumericQ` for `NDSolve` to yield a solution. I'm using MMA 11.2 on macOS 10.13.

Comment: @xzczd I read through much of [Events and Discontinuities in Differential Equations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents.html) and discovered that adding `WhenEvent[
 Re[Sqrt[\[Rho]0[t] \[Lambda]k[t]] Sqrt[
    1 - \[Rho]0[t] \[Lambda]k[t]]] == 0, "CrossDiscontinuity"]` to the list of differential equations I feed into `NDSolve` lets it skip right over the discontinuity near $t = -3$. The calculation takes less than 20 seconds and the resulting plots look exactly as expected. Currently still doing additional testing with different event functions and actions.